# Delete whole case if value is bigger than 0 and 1

Tags: r

So I have some data and in a column there are some values like this:

df <- matrix(c(1,0,3,1,0,0,99,2))

Now I want to delete the whole case if the value is bigger than 0 and 1 or not 0 and 1.

So I have:

1
0
3
1
0
0
99
2

And I want to delete the rows bigger than 0 and 1
This would then look like:

1
0
1
0
0

How would I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "delete"? Set those values to 0 or NA, or actually remove the elements (i.e. resulting in a smaller matrix)?

Comment: I want to delete the rows which have values bigger than 0 and 1

Comment: So you wan tot keep only 0 ???? Please add the expected output for your example

Comment: You can use `df[df %in% c(0, 1)]`, however, technically speaking 1 is also bigger than 0...

Comment: Would this also work with a specific column like df$age?

Comment: `df[df$age %in% c(0, 1), ]` keeps only rows of df where the value for age is either 0 or 1

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean by?

```
> df[df %in% c(0, 1)]
[1] 1 0 1 0 0
>
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will maintain the matrix class in your result (which is technically only a one-dimensional vector):

```
(df <- matrix(c(1,0,3,1,0,0,99,2)))
#      [,1]
# [1,]    1
# [2,]    0
# [3,]    3
# [4,]    1
# [5,]    0
# [6,]    0
# [7,]   99
# [8,]    2

(df <- as.matrix(df[df %in% c(0,1),]))
#      [,1]
# [1,]    1
# [2,]    0
# [3,]    1
# [4,]    0
# [5,]    0
```

Comment: Yes I only made a vector, but my data consists of many columns. So I would like to do that for exmaple with the column df$age. How would I do that?

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1199289)